# Over 110,000 questions unananswered as of 2017. Is this a matter of concern?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

SuperUser currently has [110,000 unanswered questions](https://superuser.com/unanswered). This means the number of unanswered Qs has [doubled over 5 years](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5386/over-54-000-questions-with-no-answers).

Should something be done about this issue? If so, what?

Comment: What has happened to the number of answered questions over the same period of time?

Comment: The same arguments in the very question you linked to for the "doubling" reference still apply here. Why does the number increasing make any difference?

Comment: There are currently 58,774 questions with **no answers**, so it is not as bad as it seems at first sight. The 110,000 is questions with **no upvoted answers**

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. Long answer: Noooooooooo

Comment: How sweet that you didn't decide to make your answer too long! Care to elaborate?

Comment: I really only needed 2 letters to get my point across, but there's a character limit